# iOS: UIScrollView not samples all values

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I would like to know specifically when the offset of the scrollView reaches the **center** of the page. Unfortunately `scrollViewDidScroll` does not samples all the values. So I am not entering the `if` every time I pass the center of the screen. How can I overcome this?

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let page = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        let offsetInPage = (scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width) - CGFloat(page)

        if offsetInPage == 0.5 { // Does not called every time

            toggleColors()
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a range (for example, 0.45..<0.55) to check it?

Comment: every comparison (`==`) with floating point numbers should trigger an alarm.

Comment: why it should ? only if the value `offsetInPage == 0.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentOffset` is updated by handling touch gesture, which couldn't be done continuously because it's not like you get messages from touch screen on every change but instead system is checking state of the touch screen in some loop. In this case it's runloop. So there could be some changes that happen between runloop iterations and are not caught by the app. Theoretically in some cases gap could be even more than whole page.

So it's better to check, what area is visible now, and calculate what color should be applied when this area is visible rather than waiting for some exact value of `contentOffset` to appear

According to your code seems like you just want to switch colors when user scrolls so that all odd pages would have one color and all the even pages - another. If so, I'd do it like that:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let page = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    let isOddPage = (page % 2 == 1)
    let offsetInPage = (scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width) - CGFloat(page)

    if (isOddPage && offsetInPage < 0.5) || (!isOddPage && offsetInPage >= 0.5) {
        switchToOddColor()
    } else {
        switchToEvenColor()
    }
}
```

Or something like that. Maybe condition is more complex in your case and maybe you have more than just two colors, but the strategy is the same.

It's also usefull to check if colors are not already set to needed value inside `switchToOddColor` and `switchToEvenColor` to avoid doing extra job.

Comment: Like your intro and explanation very much!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to 1) check a value representing if the page offset is greater than the half and 2) toggle colors only if the value is changed:

```
var isOverHalf: Bool = true
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let page = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        let offsetInPage = (scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width) - CGFloat(page)

        let isOverHalf = offsetInPage > 0.5
        If self.isOverHalf != isOverHalf {
            toggleColors()
        }
        self.isOverHalf = isOverHalf
}
```

Maybe this is a kind of unwanted answer though, here is also [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) version:

```
scrollView.rx.didSCroll
    .map { [weak scrollView] _ in scrollView?.offsetInPage ?? 0 }
    .map { $0 > 0.5 }
    .distinctUntilChanged() // this line prevents toggleColors() from being called for the same values multiple times
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.toggleColors()
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

extension UIScrollView {
    var offsetInPage: CGFloat {
        let page = contentOffset.x / frame.size.width
        return page - floor(page)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of you use floats to compare, i suggest to use ranges like here:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let page = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    let offsetInPage = (scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width) - CGFloat(page)

    if (0.45..<0.55).contains(offsetInPage) {
        print("near to center")
        toggleColors()
    }

}
```

functions like `scrollViewDidScroll` cannot triggers on every float values, because it is impossible! You need to check like above or try to catch 2 values `lowerValue`, `biggerValue`.

Comment: I think this will produce unwanted results as this will be triggered multiple times when scrollview is scrolled in one direction.